# JBOSS Fuse - How to Mediate Multiple Services

Tags: esb, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have multiple services running in remote machine.

I need to create a single interface for invoking all the services running.

Questions:

Is it possible to achieve this in JBOSS Fuse?

If yes, Which EIP do I need to use to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to study some of the EIPs at the Apache Camel project to get more familiar with them

- http://camel.apache.org/eip

There is also a printable reference card with the most common

- http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/apache-camel-update

And the EIPs you may want to take a look at is multicast / pipes and filters / recipient list / routing slip etc.

But yeah JBoss Fuse (with Camel) can for sure exposes an interface and invoke multiple services and aggregate that as a single response for the interface.

Basically dig in and research, get your hands dirty, and learn by doing. There is a ton of information about Apache Camel (a great starting point to learn first), at the Camel website and at the many videos / blogs / books etc. Check out some of these links

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-integration-apache
- http://camel.apache.org/articles.html
- http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html